# SAS CLI execute error: [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver]String data, right truncated

Tags: sql, excel, sas, odbc

I have a SaS script and is suppose to get data from a SQL Server. I finally manage to get a connection working but am now getting a new error. Below is a screen shot and also I pasted the text:
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EItHK.png)

```
NOTE: SAS variable labels, formats, and lengths are not written to DBMS tables.
ERROR: CLI execute error: [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver]String data, right
truncated
ERROR: A pipe communications routine failed: The pipe has been ended. (109)
ERROR: A pipe communications routine failed: The pipe is being closed. (232)
ERROR: A pipe communications routine failed: The pipe is being closed. (232)
ERROR: A pipe communications routine failed: The pipe is being closed. (232)
ERROR: A pipe communications routine failed: The pipe is being closed. (232)
ERROR: CLI disconnect failed: Server communication failure.
```

I do not know anything about SaS but I need to get this working this within the next day or 2. Does anyone know how to fix this error? I hope I do not need to add anything to the script, I had inherited this from the previous data guy and it has worked.

Comment: Please post text as text and not as photographs.   Did you try executing the join in the remote database instead of asking SAS to implicitly push the join into the remote database?

Comment: somewhere higher up, there should be a `libname SQL ...;` statement. Could you share the lines of the log about it?